# How would you call methods from a different class in a Razor class/file in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I was interested in creating a Blazor WebAssembly app

I created a separate class **SimpleMaths-class** containing small basic math logic

**SimpleMaths-class**

```
namespace MyFirstApp.Classes
{
    public class SimpleMaths
    {
        public int SumOfTwo(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

        public int DistractionOfTwo(int a, int b)
        {
            return a - b;
        }

        public int Division(int a, int b)
        {
            return a/ b;
        }
    }
}
```

In **_Imports.razor** I added the following statement because I want to use this class throughout the Project:

```
@using MyFirstApp.Classes
```

**Razor** file contains the following

```
<p>Number One:</p>
<input type="number" id="Num1" @bind="Num1"/>

<p>Number Two:</p>
<input type="number" id="Num2" @bind="Num2"/>

<p>
    <br/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Summerize">Sum</button>
</p>

<p>
    Sum: @Sum
</p>

@code {
    SimpleMaths sim = new SimpleMaths();
    private int Num1, Num2, Sum = 0;

    private void Summerize()
    {
        Sum = sim.SumOfTwo(Num1, Num2);
    }

}
```

The above methodology works fine, but I'm interested in knowing other (or easier) ways to accomplish the task.

I think the following scenario is a better approach than the one currently implemented:

Providing Num1 and Num2 as **parameters** and **calling SumOfTwo-method** (from SimpleMaths) during the **on click** of Sum-button. Is this approach achievable? If yes, how does this look like?

My **goal** is not to apply business logic throughout my page, I'm just interested in knowing how this works if in case I'll deal with these kind of scenarios in the future.

Comment: I think you should expand on what you mean by "Providing parameters to Sum-button and calling SumOfTwo-method (from SimpleMaths) when clicking the Sum-button." as I'm not able to follow along on what exactly you are after.

Comment: I changed the sentence you just quoted. I want to find out how to work with classes in razor pages

Comment: Still not clear. And you need to focus this quite well, otherwise it'll get closed as 'too opinionated'.  When user input is required this is as good as it will get.

Comment: SimpleMaths could (should) be injected but I don't think that's what you're asking here.

Comment: _"how would you solve it"_  - what is _it_ here?   You haven't managed to ask that clearly.

Comment: Check @enet's solution it's exactly what I was looking for.
And what part isn't clear to you?

Comment: OK, so you wanted to turn a perfect stateless service into something with state and with UI concerns mixed in?  It's such a giant leap backwards, architercturally.

Comment: Best option: keep your original code.

Comment: Why don't you just make it a static class?

Comment: @Grizzlly I'll definitely give it a try ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to implement what you want. The following one attempts to remain as true as possible to your wish...

Create a service class to perform the math calculation. ( This is only for instruction purposes, so if you get errors, it's your fault)

### SimpleMaths.cs

```
internal class SimpleMaths
    {
        public int CurrentSum { get; private set; }

        public void SumOfTwo(int a, int b)
        {
            CurrentSum =  a + b;
            StateChanged?.Invoke();
        }

        public void DistractionOfTwo(int a, int b)
        {
            CurrentSum = a - b;
            StateChanged?.Invoke();
        }

        public void Division(int a, int b)
        {
            try
            {
                CurrentSum = a / b;
                StateChanged?.Invoke();
            }
            catch { }
        }

        public event Action StateChanged;
    }
```

Add the service class to the DI container as scoped:

`services.AddScoped<SimpleMaths>();`

### Usage in Index.razor

```
@page "/"

@inject BlazorApp5.SimpleMaths SimpleMaths



<p>Number One:</p>
<input type="number" id="Num1" @bind="Num1" />

<p>Number Two:</p>
<input type="number" id="Num2" @bind="Num2" />

<p>
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => SimpleMaths.SumOfTwo(Num1, Num2))">Add</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => SimpleMaths.DistractionOfTwo(Num1, Num2))">Distract</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => SimpleMaths.Division(Num1, Num2))">Divide</button>
</p>

<p>
    Sum: @SimpleMaths.CurrentSum.ToString()
</p>

@code {
   
    private int Num1, Num2;
        

}
```

Note that you should inject the SimpleMaths service into the Index component. Note also that we call the methods of the service directly from the lambda expressions assigned to the `@onclick` directive of each button element.

Answer (score 0):

Another working example using a static class

**Razor file**

```
<p>Number One:</p>
<input type="number" id="Num1" @bind="Num1"/>

<p>Number Two:</p>
<input type="number" id="Num2" @bind="Num2"/>

<p>
    <br/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => SimpleMaths.SumOfTwo(Num1, Num2))">Sum</button>
</p>

<p>
    Result: @SimpleMaths.Result
</p>

@code {
    private int Num1, Num2;
    
}
```

The **static class**

```
public static class SimpleMaths
{
    public static int Result { get; private set; }
    public static void SumOfTwo(int a, int b)
    {
        Result = a + b;
    }

    public static void DistractionOfTwo(int a, int b)
    {
        Result = a - b;
    }

    public static void Division(int a, int b)
    {
        Result = a / b;
    }
}
```